Have DC Comics media addressed Clayface's vulnerability to explosive implants?
In the 2024 anime series Suicide Squad Isekai, we see Clayface, the shape-shifting Batman villain with a malleable clay-like body, joining the infamous team. As is tradition for the Suicide Squad, he's fitted with a neck bomb that Amanda Waller can detonate at will. This bomb also automatically explodes if it doesn't receive an A.R.G.U.S. radio signal for 72 hours.

I'm thinking that given Clayface's powers to manipulate his clay-like body, he can simply eject the bomb. And that even if the bomb detonated, the explosion would not actually harm his reformable clay body.
Despite these apparent advantages, Clayface doesn't attempt to remove the bomb and participates in Waller's missions.
Has the comics universe or other DC media ever addressed this scenario? Is there a precedent where Clayface was implanted with a bomb? If so, did they use some special tech to prevent him from removing it with his shape-shifting powers and make the bomb capable of harming or killing him?
Episode 8 update:

 Clayface's bomb does explode, but he's revealed to be unharmed since he can apparently position his brain and heart wherever he desires. Still, I'm interested in whether other DC media have addressed this scenario.


It reminds me that in the Justice League animated series, when Clayface joins Grodd's Secret Society to fight the Justice League, they end the fight by putting fireworks into him and igniting them, which seemed to have killed him because he never came back. But there's a difference between using lots of fireworks and just a bomb implant in the neck. https://youtu.be/c3j9LCiQGb4?t=188

In Batman TAS episode "Growing Pain", Commissioner Gordon retrieves a knocked out Clayface after he survived an explosion in a chemical factory, so he's at least strong enough to survive explosives, generally speaking. https://youtu.be/LU6udtK6rLc?t=228

@Clockwork: "there's a difference between using lots of fireworks and just a bomb implant in the neck" [citation needed]

@PaulD.Waite I meant that in the heat of the battle, they managed to stick fireworks onto his body to blow him up, whereas the neck implant is used as a leverage to blackmail him. But in theory, he could just turn into mud to dispose of the implant.

An unsupported, but inferred answer would be that they've already shown multiple restraints on Clayface's powers in those two episodes (his initial arm restraints, the magic handcuffs, and the magic fields). It's possible his implant is coated in whatever restrains his power, so he can't eject it without ejecting the base of his neck as flesh and dying.

@manofsteelanswers.com Interesting thought! I'm curious if the comics or other DC media have explored similar ideas—perhaps some advanced tech or magical solution that prevents Clayface from simply ejecting implants. It would be interesting to see how they've handled this potential loophole in his abilities.

That edit you added is even stranger, because in the DCAU, Clayface doesn't have much in common with a human anymore, anatomically speaking. As in, he doesn't seem to have any vital organs. In one episode, he was practically entirely dissolved in water and miraculously survived when he drifted near a chemical that allowed him to solidify. And in another, a wealthy collector had him divided and stored as collection in separate barrels. When the villains came to pour out the barrels, he just reformed himself and was very much alive and healthy (which shouldn't be possible if he had vital organs)

I'm guessing this is a very different kind of Clay Face who's more of a human with shapeshifting abilities, than literally living mud.

@Clockwork Yep, Suicide Squad Isekai's Clayface is a departure from the DCAU one. Unlike the DCAU version, this one has vulnerable human organs. He rarely transforms fully into clay, mostly staying in human form.

I initially posted these as comments because they don't actually answer the question, but I figured they're still interesting enough to be worth posting as an answer.
In episode Secret Society from the Justice League cartoon, the aforementioned league stick lots of fireworks into him and igniting them all, seemingly killing him off because he never came back in the DC animated universe:



However, in the same universe, episode Growing Pain from The New Batman Adventures, at the end of the episode, he was shown to survive an explosion at a chemical factory, although the explosion knocked him out:



But that doesn't explain why he doesn't attempt to remove the bomb, nor why Amanda Waller thinks a mere neck bomb would be good enough to deter him.

Now, if we wanted to tread into speculation, maybe they're using sensors to ignite some kind of anti Clayface bomb if he attempted to remove it, but I think that's a wild-goose chase.

Interesting examples! So bombs can affect Clayface, but with varying results. I wonder if there's any precedent for him being unable to remove something implanted in his body due to advanced tech or other factors. That might explain why he doesn't just eject Waller's bomb.
